# Implementing Single Sign On for WCF service(Web Applications) Using OpenSSO

Tags: wcf, single-sign-on, wcf-security, saml-2.0, opensso

I am new to Single Sign On concept and I am trying to implement SSO for wcf service web applications using OpenSSO with SAML protocol. I couldn't get the clear idea from the internet sources that how i should proceed/start. Can u guys help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If new to SSO and WCF, you're probably not going to like the answer: write your own Binding.

WCF is awesome because Microsoft built the whole thing extensibly. So in theory you can do exactly what they did with netTcpBinding or wsHttpBinding. Say you have a VAX mainframe sitting around - you could theoretically write a Binding for it. Same with "Protocol XYZ" and OpenSSO. Since I don't see an OpenSsoBinding available out there, I conclude you'll have to whip up your own.

Implementation details are beyond my knowledge and the scope of the OP, but you can get the starting guidance here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730305(v=vs.110).aspx

HTH!